# How to straighten bowed wood outdoors

Tags: wood-movement

I have a garden bench with horizontal slats on the back rest, one of the slats is bowed. Has anybody got any ideas of how to straighten it out ?

Comment: Many Q&A already about how to straighten bowed lumber. This is essentially a duplicate of any number of Qs found via searching "straighten".